# Neo4j and Cluster Analysys

Tags: cluster-computing, neo4j, cluster-analysis, graph-databases

I'm developing a web application that will heavily depend on its ability to make suggestions on items basing on users with similar preferences. A friend of mine told me that what I'm looking for - mathematically - is some Cluster Analysis algorithm. On the other hand, here on SO, I was told that Neo4j (or some other Graph DB) was the kind DB that I should have approached for this task (the preferences one).

I started studying both this tools, and I'm having some doubts.
For Cluster Analysis purposes it looks to me that a standard SQL DB would still be the perfect choice, while Neo4j would be better suited for a Neural Network kind of approach (although still perfectly fit for the task).

Am I missing something? Am I trying to use the wrong tools combination?

I would love to hear some ideas on the subject.

Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this depends on your data. neo4j is capable to provide even complex recommendations in real-time for one particular node - let's say you want to recommend to a user some product and this can be handle within a graph db in real-time

whereas using some clustering system is the best way to do recommendations for all users at once (and than maybe save it somewhere so you wouldn't need to calculate it again).

**the computational difference:**

- neo4j has has no initialization cost and can give you one recommendations in an acceptable time
- clustering needs more time for initialization (e.g. not in seconds but most likely in minutes/hours) and is better to calculate the recommendations for the whole dataset. in fact, taking strictly the time for one calculations for a specific user this clustering can do it faster than neo4j but the big restriction is the initial initialization - thus not good for real-time application

**the practical difference**:

- if you have **mostly static data** and is ok for you to do recommendations once in a time than do clustering with SQL
- if you got dynamical data where the data are being updated with each interaction and is necessary for you to **always provide the newest recommendation**, than use neo4j

Comment: That's what I thought. Second part of my question was: do you think that I should study/need some mathematical graph theory, or should I just try to dig deeper into the database and my actual knowledge should be enough to reach the needed results?

Comment: if you are selfteacher and have no college background, than dont waste your time with studying topics which are best to be taught by a teacher than by reading materials. in this case simply try finding solution for you specific problems - like post here on stackoverflow your data and goal you want to reach and ask how to do it. but this is the fastest way from the practical point of view of how to get things done quickly. if you just want to know things and you like studying than go ahead

Comment: and for your second part of question - i dont know your case and cant give you answer. either way, you should know what are both technologies good for and thus some theory check on both of them would be beneficial. than, you can decide which one is good for your specific problem

Comment: I like having a general idea of the subject before going deep into a topic. Therefore it's my habit to buy at least a university-level book to have a good overview. This prevents me from taking sub-optimal approaches that will result in wasting time in later stages. Unluckily now I don't have nearly enough time for that, and I'll gladly accept your suggestion. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on various topics related to recommendation and clustering with neo4j.
I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but depending on how you implement you data on the graph, you can easily work out clustering algorithms based on counting links to various type of nodes.

If you plan correctly you nodes and relationships, you can then identify group of nodes that share most common links to a set of category.

Answer (score 2):

let me introduce Reco4J (http://www.reco4j.org), is is an open source framework that provide recommendation based on graph database source. It uses neo4j as graph database management system.
Have a look at it and contact us if you are interested in support. 
It is in a really early release but we are working hard to provide extended documentation and new interesting features.

Cheers,
Alessandro

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I find the project to be too much at early stages (ie: with little documentation) to be approached by a complete beginner as me with even a little margin of confidence

Comment: The next release will be soon available with more details in it. In the mean time if you contact us we can provide you all the information and support to get started working with reco4j.

Comment: @AlessandroNegro does it do real time recommendations?

Comment: @Nerrve we are working to real time recommendation. Please contact us directly so that we can discuss about your specific use case, for contact details have a look here: http://www.reco4j.org/contacts.jsp.

Comment: well, i'm not too sure myself about the exact requirements. i'll need some time to gather all of that data to give you. meanwhile, i found a paper that you might like http://net.pku.edu.cn/report/1. it (Fast Algorithms for Querying and Mining Large Graphs) http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~htong/

Comment: great thanks, please fill free to contact us whenever you would like to start, also just to have an idea. we know that there is no documentation on reco4j but we are trying to write it and provide it as soon as possible. In the mean time we can help our user directly.